# Scrolling Text in Chrome Disappears after some time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a marquee-like effect on the top of this page. The text is coded to continuously scroll horizontally. The text should continuously scroll with no gaps. It's working in Safari and Firefox, but for some reason in Chrome, after a few seconds, it just cuts off. The weird thing is, if I highlight the area where I know the text is, it reappears. Do you all know why this is happening? Any insight/help would be appreciated as I am a student learning how to code! I've attached screenshots, of how it first looks when the text disappears, and the other screenshot shows it reappearing after I highlight the area.

[Screenshot of Text Disappearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XylYy.png)

[Screenshot of me Highlighting the area of the scrollable text, makes the text visible again on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D47CF.png)

I am using MacOS Catalina Version 10.15.7 and my Chrome version is Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (x86_64). I showed this code to a friend as well, and they experienced the same issue in Chrome.

**UPDATE: Looks like this issue is related to overflow:hidden**

Below is my html

```
<section class="intro section section-pad bg-cover" id="intro">
  <div class="copy container">
    <div class="marquee">
      <!-- Here we add the title in multiple repeating times using javascript --> 
      <span>Event -- January 1-2, 2020, Zoom</span>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.section {
  /*each section will take 100% of the height of browser */
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* Will help to vertically align container box */
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

/* Provide padding to left and right of section */
.section-pad {
  padding-left: 5vw;
  padding-right: 5vw;
}

.container {
  /* Take the width of widest content box */
  max-width: 780px;
    /* Center our box horizontally and vertically using flex on .section */
  margin: auto;
}

.marquee {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3vh;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /*Each letter will be 5% of viewport width */
  font-size: 5vw;
  /* As tall as text */
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /*no scrollbars */
  overflow:  hidden;

}

.marquee span {
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-animation-name: moveLeft; 
 animation-name: moveLeft; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 500s; 
         animation-duration: 500s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  /*This will ensure the text stays all on the same line */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Our span is inline by default, so change it to block */
  display: block;
  /*Help with animation */
  position: relative;
}


@keyframes moveLeft {
  0% {
   /* transform: translate(0);*/
   -webkit-transform: translatex(0);
           transform: translatex(0);
  }
  
  100% {
   /* transform: translateX(-3000vw); */
     -webkit-transform: translatex(-3000vw);
             transform: translatex(-3000vw);
  }
}



@-webkit-keyframes moveLeft {
  0% {
   /* transform: translate(0);*/
   -webkit-transform: translatex(0);
           transform: translatex(0);
  }
  
  100% {
   /* transform: translateX(-3000vw); */
     -webkit-transform: translatex(-3000vw);
             transform: translatex(-3000vw);
  }
}
```

And Finally here is the Javascript used

```
function makeMarquee () {
  const title ='Event -- January 1-2, 2021, Zoom'


//use Array constructor to create an empty list with a length of 50 that is filled with the title. 
//We can join all the contents of array using dash
const marqueeText = new Array(500).fill(title).join(' -- ')
//query Selector same as $ jquery, grab the span tags
const marquee = document.querySelector('.marquee span')

//set the text of span to be the marqueeText
marquee.innerHTML =  marqueeText
  

}

makeMarquee()
```

Below is a Snippet as well

```js
function makeMarquee () {
  const title ='Event -- January 1-2, 2021, Zoom'


//use Array constructor to create an empty list with a length of 50 that is filled with the title. 
//We can join all the contents of array using dash
const marqueeText = new Array(500).fill(title).join(' -- ')
//query Selector same as $ jquery, grab the span tags
const marquee = document.querySelector('.marquee span')

//set the text of span to be the marqueeText
marquee.innerHTML =  marqueeText
  

}

makeMarquee()
```

```css
.section {
  /*each section will take 100% of the height of browser */
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* Will help to vertically align container box */
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

/* Provide padding to left and right of section */
.section-pad {
  padding-left: 5vw;
  padding-right: 5vw;
}

.container {
  /* Take the width of widest content box */
  max-width: 780px;
    /* Center our box horizontally and vertically using flex on .section */
  margin: auto;
}

.marquee {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3vh;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /*Each letter will be 5% of viewport width */
  font-size: 5vw;
  /* As tall as text */
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /*no scrollbars */
  overflow:  hidden;

}

.marquee span {
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-animation-name: moveLeft; 
 animation-name: moveLeft; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 500s; 
         animation-duration: 500s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  /*This will ensure the text stays all on the same line */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Our span is inline by default, so change it to block */
  display: block;
  /*Help with animation */
  position: relative;
}


@keyframes moveLeft {
  0% {
   /* transform: translate(0);*/
   -webkit-transform: translatex(0);
           transform: translatex(0);
  }
  
  100% {
   /* transform: translateX(-3000vw); */
     -webkit-transform: translatex(-3000vw);
             transform: translatex(-3000vw);
  }
}



@-webkit-keyframes moveLeft {
  0% {
   /* transform: translate(0);*/
   -webkit-transform: translatex(0);
           transform: translatex(0);
  }
  
  100% {
   /* transform: translateX(-3000vw); */
     -webkit-transform: translatex(-3000vw);
             transform: translatex(-3000vw);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="intro section section-pad bg-cover" id="intro">

  <div class="copy container">
    <div class="marquee">
      <!-- Here we add the title in multiple repeating times using javascript -->
      <span>Event -- January 1-2, 2020, Zoom</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The gap in Chrome (and Edge) is caused by setting `overflow: hidden` on the marquee. The browsers seem to sense that they have shown enough (I am not sure what enough means in this context as the max-width is set quite low at 768px) and that they must not show the overflow but they carry on with the animation so after 50 seconds it starts again from the beginning.

Why the other browsers (Firefox, Safari) don't honor the overflow I have not been able to discover.

If you change the .marquee to have overflow: visible then all these browsers will continue the animation with no gaps.

UPDATE: in addition section is given `overflow: hidden` and the timing and distance travelled has been altered to prevent an x-overflow bar showing.

```js
function makeMarquee () {
      const title ='Event -- January 1-2, 2021, Zoom'


    //use Array constructor to create an empty list with a length of 50 that is filled with the title. 
    //We can join all the contents of array using dash
    const marqueeText = new Array(500).fill(title).join(' -- ')
    //query Selector same as $ jquery, grab the span tags
    const marquee = document.querySelector('.marquee span');

    //set the text of span to be the marqueeText
    marquee.innerHTML =  marqueeText
   // setTimeout(function () {marquee.style.animationName = 'moveLeft';},1000);
    }

    makeMarquee()
```

```css
    .section {
      /*each section will take 100% of the height of browser */
      min-height: 100vh;
      /* Will help to vertically align container box */
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden; /* added to prevent 'gap' appearing on Chrome/Edge */     
    }

    /* Provide padding to left and right of section */
    .section-pad {
      padding-left: 5vw;
      padding-right: 5vw;
    }

    .container {
      /* Take the width of widest content box */
      max-width: 780px;
        /* Center our box horizontally and vertically using flex on .section */
      margin: auto;
    }

    .marquee {
      position: absolute;
      top: 3vh;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      /*Each letter will be 5% of viewport width */
      font-size: 5vw;
      /* As tall as text */
      line-height: 1;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      /*no scrollbars */
      /* but - make visible otherwise Chrome/Edge stop showing overflowed bits so get a gap */
      overflow: visible; /* was hidden not visible */
    }

    .marquee span {
     transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
     animation-name: moveLeft;
             animation-duration: 550s; /* altered from 50s as have longer for the text to travel now */
              animation-timing-function: linear;
              animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      /*This will ensure the text stays all on the same line */
      white-space: nowrap;
      /* Our span is inline by default, so change it to block */
      display: block;
      /*Help with animation */
      position: relative;
      width: 4000vw; /* this is a bit hacky but does the trick - fools Chrome etc into thinking overflow is OK */
    }

    @keyframes moveLeft {
      0% {
               transform: translateX(0);
      }
      
      100% {
               transform: translateX(-100%);/* was 3000vw */
      }
    }
```

```html
<section class="intro section section-pad bg-cover" id="intro">

      <div class="copy container">
        <div class="marquee">
          <!-- Here we add the title in multiple repeating times using javascript -->
          <span>Event -- January 1-2, 2020, Zoom</span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to look at this! Thanks, indeed the culprit seems to be overflow:hidden. I see no gaps now, but now I have this giant horizontal scrollbar -- is there anyway to remove the scrollbar and have no gaps in the animation?

Comment: That’s interesting, I did not see a scroll bar, though I should have expected one. Which browser and OS are you on?

Comment: I am currently using Chrome (Version 87.0.4280.88) and Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7 -- but I just checked and actually see the scrollbar in Firefox and Safari as well (makes sense I guess since now overflow is no longer hidden)

Comment: Apologies, I'd tested on various  mobile emulators and of course they don't have scroll bars - I see the bars on Windows 10. The problem is that the section is overflowing which is giving the horizontal bar. A combination of hiding that and setting a wide width on the marquee seems to do the trick. I'll test a bit more then update the snippet.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! I for some reason missed the notification that you had updated the answer. So when you set the span to  width: 4000vw; -- how does that work? Just wondering since .marquee is set to be 100% of the container.

Comment: TBH I don't really know - it's a random large ficure! I just kept as much of your original code as I could. Possibly a different way, just 3 copies of the text in different divs and animate each one starting at 100% and having a delay on the start times would work as well.

Comment: ok thanks I appreciate it! I may to rewrite it and make another post about it.